# how to substring from a string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following is a line of  huge .txt file and i am reading it line by line. I need the value of second column.  In this line, I need to extract 'C9006'.

> Mr ABC|C9006|The white field,
>   ON|493-493-4939|493-493-4939|YR|Inactive

Note : The delimiter char is pipe sign '|'. The length of second column is not consistent.

Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String value = "A|B|C";
String secondColumn = value.split("|")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method of [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = input.Split('|')[1];
```