# Substring in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

**"01 ABC"**
**"123 DEF"**

How can I get the value of **"01"** and **"123"** in asp.net?

I have tried the following code:

```
Dim ddlSession As String = "01 ABC"
Dim getSpaceIndex As Integer = ddlSession.IndexOf(" ")
Dim getSessionCode As String = ddlSession.Remove(getSpaceIndex)
```

but the getSpaceIndex will keep return -1 to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to substring from a string using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034146/how-to-substring-from-a-string-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you want.

If you want the substring until the space character, you can use:

```
string ddlSessionText = "01 ABC";
string sessionCode = ddlSessionText.Substring(0, ddlSessionText.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: @Wee - Then this should suit you well.

Comment: return error: {"Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length"}

Comment: @Wee - You probably don't actually have a space in your input string. Double-check that.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Substring(0, string.IndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split.

Assuming you are using C# in your ASP.NET page:

```
string s = "01 ABC";
s.split(' ')[0]; // will give you 01
s = "123 DEF";
s.split(' ')[0]; // will give you 123
```